# Cancelling timeouts in a Marionette Backbone view that has closed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using Marionette and Backbone in a single page app to manage the opening and closing of views.

When an itemview is closed (e.g. its model has been removed from a bound collection), events in the itemview are correctly destroyed.

However, where I'm using jquery animation or setTimeout, the 'success' callbacks are still fired and invariable trigger an exception because the DOM elements they're looking for are no longer on the page.

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function () {
        self.ui.$loading.fadeIn(528);
    }, 1000);
```

What's the right way of handling these cases?  Should I simply check that the DOM elements are present, or use a try catch or is there a more elegant solution built into Marionette that I'm not aware of?

Would a deferred promise work better?

Answer (score 0):

Bind them to the view and using the onBeforeClose event, remove them.

```
class TheView extends Marionette.ItemView
    initialize: ->
        @doomsday = setTimeout ->
            console.log 'boom'
        , 3000

    onBeforeClose: ->
        @doomsday.clearTimeout()
```

Something like that should work but it depends on you keeping all your timeouts or intervals in check